# How to get a random word from a given list of words

Tags: c#

my string array has got a list of words like man, ran etc. Can somebody help me to randomly pick up a word from my string array and store it in a variable myword.

Comment: Is this a console app or winform?

Comment: Have you tried something? Can you share the code you wrote?

Comment: Have you tried using the `Random` object?

Comment: Sorry i am not able paste my code in here it keeps prompting me to indent spaces and though i keep doing it. It just pushes me off. I don't know how to get the random stuff working

Comment: You can select your code and press `Control - K` when you're posting it.

Comment: Or you can post it as it is and someone will eventually edit your post to make the code readable... done that. :)

Answer (score 10):

```
Random r = new Random();

string[] words = {"man", "rat", "cow", "chicken"};

Console.WriteLine(words[r.Next(0, words.Length)]);
```

or

```
string word = words[r.Next(0, words.Length)];
```

Be careful when using `Random`, though. This is a pseudorandom number generator so you may not get the expected results if you use it incorrectly.

Comment: There's a slight error - should be:  
`string word = words[r.Next(0, words.Length - 1)];`